# Wondering what the phrase " guide overall corporate agenda" mean in following context

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Lachlan Murdoch, who has been serving as a director at News Corp and 21st Century Fox, will work closely with senior management to develop global strategies and guide the overall corporate agenda, the company said in a statement on Wednesday.

<sub>source: 
http://mobile.reuters.com/article/topNews/idUSBREA2P0JQ20140326?irpc=932</sub>

My intuition is that it means: *to help all problems related to the corporation be solved.*  Based on my perception, the word "agenda" has to do with "problems"  ... the word " overall" just means "all"!

Comment: Your perception might be sharpened by using a dictionary to look up the words *overall* and *agenda*.

Comment: 'Agenda,' in this case, suggests 'Business Plan.'  I believe 'Overall' is implying 'complete' here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the phrase, "Guide overall corporate agenda," means to create strategies and guides to define the aim or goal or tasks of the company. In simple terms, that Mr. Murdoch will help the company set their goals and then achieve them...

Comment: you are right, but wondering if you could help me establishing the analysis you made using the words. I MEAN what does "overall" mean here ? Or what part of speech are " overall" and "corporate" in this context?

Comment: @user5036 *overall* and *corporate* are adjectives, and *agenda* is a  noun. Their meanings may be found in any dictionary.